# jquery mobile custom listview formatting

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

So I'm working on a web app that makes use of the jquery mobile framework and I was hoping there was a way to further customize the appearance of list view elements. Specifically, I would like to be able position text practically at will, and also size text appropriately. I know jquery mobile has the header tag support built in, as well as a way for an element with class=ui-li-aside to appear on the top right of the list element in smaller text.

However, I ideally want a reusable list view element that has slightly different options. For starters, I want a 1 character title left-justified in the list element, with a font basically filling the entire height of the list item. Then on the right, instead of a text element thats justified right and positioned towards the top, I would like something that is vertically aligned in the center and right aligned. Finally, I want a third text element that is left aligned just to the left of the big 1 character-title, spanning the entire middle of the list view element.

Overall, I want each style list view element to be capable of something like this: (this is actually a picture of a UITableViewCell, but the gist is the same)

[image]

The count bubbles are taken care of natively in query mobile, just need to figure out how to set up classes for the three types of other text I want to display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ThemeRoller seems good for customizing colors, fonts, borders,... but not for positioning the elements in a different way. I think you will need to write your own .css files and overwrite classes like `ui-li-heading`, `ui-li-aside` or `ui-li-desc`.
Good luck

Comment: i've noticed ui-li-aside used side by side with ui-li-desc. what is the exact difference between the two?

Comment: AFAIK the difference seems to be that `ui-li-aside` class is used for accessory components aligned to the right, while `ui-li-desc` is for the main left-aligned components.

Comment: i'm not sure about that actually. it seems as if ui-li-desc is assigned to any free tags within the <li></li> tags. It also ends up being assigned to ui-li-aside component after the jquery has rendered.

Comment: It seems that, apart from the `ui-li-heading`, any other component gets the `ui-li-desc` class. I think you will have to create your own classes for each component and define them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would be possible to use the ThemeRoller which came with JQM 1.0, I think its the most accurate way to provide the 'reusability'. But I think you have to adapt the special characteristics you want individually, like filling the text height to 100%.

http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/

zY